# what is the yakuake alternative for unity desktop?

Tags: 11.04, unity, command-line

is there any alternate for yakuake for the unity desktop, when i log in unless i'm in KDE, i cant open yakuake.

```
sudo apt-get install yakuake
```

returns nothing on unity, while on KDE it installed perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used yakuake but changed it for guake. To install guake, open a terminal and type this command:

`sudo aptitude install guake`

Guake doesn't have as many features as Yakuake but works better in a gnome or unity desktop. Also try tilda, it is even more lightweight than guake. To install tilda, type this command in the terminal

`sudo aptitude install tilda`

Good luck.